# in react useEffect life cycle, i am getting infinite result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react hook life cycle, When i login with another account, state doesn't updates. if I remove dependency array , the errors blows up of memory exceeded of updates

```js
const [admin, setAdmin] = useState({});
  
useEffect(() => {
    const jwt = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (jwt) {
      const user = jwtDecode(jwt);
      setAdmin(user);
    }
}, [admin])
```

I just want that if the user logged in with another account, the state should update immediately.

Comment: Well, yes. You always get a new object for `admin`. Changing the state cause rerender and new call to effect.

Answer (score 0):

That's because, you're setting the state in `useEffects` and hence triggering it again and again...

Whenever, `state` changes, `useEffects` get triggered if the same state has been passed as a dependency in it. That's exactly what you've done.

To fix this, Move `setAdmin(user);` in another method or remove `[admin]` from the dependency.